# python list modification to list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am trying to learn python (just finished *Learn Python the Hard Way* book!), but I seem to be struggling a bit with lists. Specifically speaking, I have a list like so:

```
x = ["/2.ext", "/4.ext", "/5.ext", "/1.ext"]
```

I would like to operate on this above list, so that it returns a list (somehow!) like so:

```
y = [ ["/1.ext", "/2.ext"], ["/1.ext", "/2.ext", "/3.ext, "/4.ext"], ["/1.ext", "/2.ext", "/3.ext", "/4.ext", "/5.ext"], ["/1.ext"] ]
```

So, essentially, each element in `x` is now turned to a list of lists. I could probably loop over `x`, store all the sequence lists in another list and then merge then together - but it just seems like there must be a better way to do it.

Would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to solve this problem.

EDIT (taking into account Martijn's comments):

Specifically, I want to generate the intermediary filenames in a sequence, ending at the number for each x list element

Comment: What are you trying to do? A combinations of every possibles list?

Comment: Where did the `"/3.ext"` come from? Your `x` list doesn't have such an element. It is unclear to me how the sublists of `y` should be generated.

Comment: is the original list supposed to have five elements not four?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What I am trying to do is run till the end of the list. So, for x[0] = "/2.ext" I would like a list which contains everything upto "/2.ext" - so, ["/1.ext", "/2.ext"] - Am I making it any clearer? So, for x[1]="/4.ext", I should have a minilist upto "/4.ext" like so: ["/1.ext", "/2.ext", "/3.ext, "/4.ext"] Hope this is a bit clearer! Please ask if it is not!

Comment: Not sure why the question is getting downvoted so fast :(

Comment: @AJW: Right, that was indeed not clear. Can you add that to your question please? You want to *generate* the intermediary filenames in a sequence, ending at the number for each `x` list element.

Comment: Your question is a) not clear (the procedure on how the output list is to be generated was missing) and b) doesn't show any evidence of effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have added it to the question now. Well, my effort to solve the problem was by looping through the entries, generating the intermediate lists and then combining them to form list of lists - but this does not sound too elegant and therefore, I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
x = ["/2.ext", "/4.ext", "/5.ext", "/1.ext"]

print [['/{}.ext'.format(j) for j in range(1,int(i[1])+1)] for i in x]

[OUTPUT]
[['/1.ext', '/2.ext'], ['/1.ext', '/2.ext', '/3.ext', '/4.ext'], ['/1.ext', '/2.ext', '/3.ext', '/4.ext', '/5.ext'], ['/1.ext']]
```

This only works for digits upto 9. I'll post update for more general solutions

HERE is the more general solution. Works for any numbers:

```
import re

x = ["/2.ext", "/4.ext", "/5.ext", "/1.ext"]

print [['/{}.ext'.format(j) for j in range(1,int(re.search(r'\d+',i).group(0))+1)] for i in x]
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks a lot. Accepted your answer. However, I have another follow up question: What if the list has: `x = ["we/2.exta", "fr/4.extb", "gb/5.extc", "de/1.extd"]`? Just wondering!